# xlabel on top axis in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, labels

I managed to get the x tick labels on the top axis of a plot, but the label of the x axis is still on the bottom axis.
I couldn't find an option to get it to the top axis. Is this possible?

Minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xticklabel pos=right, xlabel={My x label}]
      \addplot coordinates { (1,1) (42,23) };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: x label is rendered on bottom axis]

Comment: Why not `xticklabel pos=upper`? Interesting...

Comment: :-) yeah, I tried that before, but it didn't work. I thought my version was too old and left it at `pos=right`. I tried it again just now and it worked. Must have been a typo back then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add the `xlabel near ticks` option to get the label above the plot.

```
\begin{axis}[xticklabel pos=right, xlabel={My x label}, xlabel near ticks]
```

Answer (score 10):

The requested feature has been added after pgfplots version 1.2.1 . Adding

`\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}`

into the preamble will solve the problem globally.

In fact, this has the same effect as described by whlt3: it sets `xlabel near ticks` (among other keys).